# Eclipse oxygen p2 repository unresponsive

Tags: eclipse, p2

Is it only on my side, or others have troubles to use the:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/
p2 repository?

My p2 directory is just in a timeout loop so I killed him for time being. A few hours ago I was able to use it happily and just right know I need to install quickly few things :/

Is it under a heavy load, or it's in middle of restructuring? For example, yesterday I noticed the Oxygen2 download was dropped.

Comment: The followup Photon release came out yesterday. Oxygen is unsupported at this point.

Comment: I was thinking Oxygen 3a would be fine. Unsupported is fine (no maintenance), allowing downloads should still be allowed, no?

Comment: Now it's back online, the next build is probably time to upgrade to Photon.

Comment: In such cases see https://status.eclipse.org/ (and/or https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com)

Comment: The problem was that the website opened in the browser, but p2 director was still timeout, so the second site wouldn't be helpful. That's why I asked if others can use it as p2 repository and was not asking if it will open in the browser. The status eclipse looks useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a temporary outage, @howlger pointed to useful resources:
https://status.eclipse.org/
and in case the repository will not even open in the browser then this can be useful as well:
https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Probably keeping track on the release schedules could avoid some surprises: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Photon/Simultaneous_Release_Plan

Comment: Looks like today, is bit flaky day as well. The download is stable enough, but few times in a year they might not be that responsible.